# Setting a class' metaclass using a decorator

Tags: python, decorator, metaclass

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121381/623518) it seems that a class' metaclass may be changed after the class has been defined by using the following*:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
    # Metaclass magic...

class A(object):
    pass

A = MyMetaClass(A.__name__, A.__bases__, dict(A.__dict__))
```

Defining a function

```
def metaclass_wrapper(cls):
    return MyMetaClass(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))
```

allows me to apply a decorator to a class definition like so,

```
@metaclass_wrapper
class B(object):
    pass
```

It seems that the metaclass magic is applied to `B`, however `B` has no `__metaclass__` attribute. Is the above method a sensible way to apply metaclasses to class definitions, even though I am definiting and re-definiting a class, or would I be better off simply writing

```
class B(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMetaClass
    pass
```

I presume there are some differences between the two methods.

---

*Note, the original answer in the linked question, `MyMetaClass(A.__name__, A.__bases__, A.__dict__)`, returns a `TypeError`:

> TypeError: type() argument 3 must be a dict, not dict_proxy

It seems that the `__dict__` attribute of `A` (the class definition) has a type `dict_proxy`, whereas the type of the `__dict__` attribute of an *instance* of `A` has a type `dict`. Why is this? Is this a Python 2.x vs. 3.x difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class has no `__metaclass__` attribute set... because you never set it!

Which metaclass to use is normally determined **by** a name `__metaclass__` set in a class block. The `__metaclass__` attribute isn't set by the metaclass. So if you invoke a metaclass directly rather than setting `__metaclass__` and letting Python figure it out, then no `__metaclass__` attribute is set.

In fact, normal classes are all instances of the metaclass `type`, so if the metaclass always set the `__metaclass__` attribute on its instances then *every* class would have a `__metaclass__` attribute (most of them set to `type`).

---

I would not use your decorator approach. It obscures the fact that a metaclass is involved (and which one), is still one line of boilerplate, and it's just messy to create a class from the 3 defining features of `(name, bases, attributes)` only to pull those 3 bits back out from the resulting class, throw the class away, and make a new class from those same 3 bits!

When you do this in Python 2.x:

```
class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

You'd get roughly the same result if you'd written this:

```
attrs = {}
attrs['__metaclass__'] = MyMeta
def __init__(self):
    pass
attrs['__init__'] = __init__
A = attrs.get('__metaclass__', type)('A', (object,), attrs)
```

In reality calculating the metaclass is more complicated, as there actually has to be a search through all the bases to determine whether there's a metaclass conflict, and if one of the bases doesn't have `type` as its metaclass and `attrs` doesn't contain `__metaclass__` then the default metaclass is the ancestor's metaclass rather than `type`. This is one situation where I expect your decorator "solution" will differ from using `__metaclass__` directly. I'm not sure exactly what would happen if you used your decorator in a situation where using `__metaclass__` would give you a metaclass conflict error, but I wouldn't expect it to be pleasant.

Also, if there are any other metaclasses involved, your method would result in them running first (possibly modifying what the name, bases, and attributes are!) and then pulling those out of the class and using it to create a new class. This could potentially be quite different than what you'd get using `__metaclass__`.

As for the `__dict__` not giving you a real dictionary, that's just an implementation detail; I would guess for performance reasons. I doubt there is any spec that says the `__dict__` of a (non-class) instance has to be the same type as the `__dict__` of a class (which is also an instance btw; just an instance of a metaclass). The `__dict__` attribute of a class is a  "dictproxy", which allows you to look up attribute keys as if it were a `dict` but still isn't a `dict`. `type` is picky about the type of its third argument; it wants a real dict, not just a "dict-like" object (shame on it for spoiling duck-typing). It's not a 2.x vs 3.x thing; Python 3 behaves the same way, although it gives you a nicer string representation of the `dictproxy`. Python 2.4 (which is the oldest 2.x I have readily available) also has `dictproxy` objects for class `__dict__` objects.

Answer (score 6):

Admittedly, I am a bit late to the party. However, I fell this was worth adding.

This is completely doable. That being said, there are plenty of other ways to accomplish the same goal. However, the decoration solution, in particular, allows for delayed evaluation ( `obj = dec(obj)` ), which using `__metaclass__` inside the class does not. In typical decorator style, my solution is below.

There is a tricky thing that you may run into if you just construct the class without changing the dictionary or copying its attributes. Any attributes that the class had previously (before decorating) will appear to be missing. So, it is absolutely essential to copy these over and then tweak them as I have in my solution.

Personally, I like to be able to keep track of how an object was wrapped. So, I added the `__wrapped__` attribute, which is not strictly necessary. It also makes it more like `functools.wraps` in Python 3 for classes. However, it can be helpful with introspection. Also, `__metaclass__` is added to act more like the normal metaclass use case.

```
def metaclass(meta):
    def metaclass_wrapper(cls):
        __name = str(cls.__name__)
        __bases = tuple(cls.__bases__)
        __dict = dict(cls.__dict__)

        for each_slot in __dict.get("__slots__", tuple()):
            __dict.pop(each_slot, None)

        __dict["__metaclass__"] = meta

        __dict["__wrapped__"] = cls

        return(meta(__name, __bases, __dict))
    return(metaclass_wrapper)
```

For a trivial example, take the following.

```
class MetaStaticVariablePassed(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        dct["passed"] = True

        return(super(MetaStaticVariablePassed, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct))

@metaclass(MetaStaticVariablePassed)
class Test(object):
    pass
```

This yields the nice result...

```
|1> Test.passed
|.> True
```

Using the decorator in the less usual, but identical way...

```
class Test(object):
    pass

Test = metaclass_wrapper(Test)
```

...yields, as expected, the same nice result.

```
|1> Test.passed
|.> True
```

Comment: In case it is useful, have this in the `metawrap` package on PyPI. Feedback on the GitHub repo is most welcome. :)

ref: https://pypi.org/project/metawrap/
ref: https://github.com/jakirkham/metawrap

Comment: The problem is that the class instance being decorated would have already been created before the decorator has a chance to influence anything. If you are not interested in influencing the behaviour of `__new__` for the current class instance, then using a decorator will work. My experience in trying to do something like this comes from attempting to modify the behaviour of Django model classes, but it seems that by the time the decorator has a chance to do anything, the class instance already exists and django will complain if we try to create it again using custom logic

Answer (score 0):

My summary of your question: "I tried a new tricky way to do a thing, and it didn't quite work.  Should I use the simple way instead?"

Yes, you should do it the simple way.  You haven't said why you're interested in inventing a new way to do it.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a decorator equivalent to setting the `__metaclass__` attribute in a class definition. I guess another part of my question is that my 'decorator' did *seem* to work, but I noticed that the decorated class has no `__metaclass__` attribute, so there is clearly a difference between the two methods; why is this?