# How to stack metaclasses

Tags: python, python-2.x, metaclass

I would like to "stack" metaclasses.

```
def dec(cls):
    class newmeta(cls.__metaclass__):
        def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            obj = cls.__metaclass__.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            obj.x *= 2 #this happens AFTER __init__ is called
    cls.__metaclass__ = newmeta
    return cls

@dec
@dec
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = 5

print Foo().x #expect 20
```

However, I don't seem to be able to access `Foo.__metaclass__` in this fashion.... in fact `("__metaclass__" in Foo.__dict__) == False`

How would one go about this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve* with this? Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5120688/3001761?

Comment: The goal is to perform a series of events after the `__init__` method is called.  I might just solve it with mixins, and call a bunch of supers at the end.

Comment: "Metaclasses are deeper magic than 99% of users should ever worry about." If there is a way to accomplish what you want without using them, do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alter existsing `cls.__metaclass__` has no effect, as metaclass determine how class built, you have to create a new class object with your metaclass:

```
def dec(cls):
    basetype = type(cls)
    class newmeta(basetype):
        def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            obj = super(newmeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            obj.x *= 2
            return obj
    new_cls = newmeta(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))
    return new_cls


@dec
@dec
class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5


o = Bar()
print o.x
```

yields:

```
20
```

ps: this method works for both python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Python 3.5+, `__metaclass__` is no longer supported, as desribed here 
[__metaclass__ in Python3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013249/metaclass-in-python3-5)