# How to set meta class while making class with type in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make some classes in runtime with `type()` and I want to set a `Meta` class while creating them. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to set metaclass after the class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120688/is-there-a-way-to-set-metaclass-after-the-class-definition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I digged more and based on gotten errors, I came up with this solution, which seems working:

```py
    attr = dict() # Add methods, vars, etc. to this dict
    meta = type("Meta", (type,), {"some_var": "some_value"})
    attr["Meta"] = meta
    print(attr)
    cls = type("class_name", (object,), attr)
```